# Trying to use delete duplicates while using any() to go through the

Tags: python, any

I am a beginner learning Python and was trying to remove duplicates from list while using any (Trying to learn `any()` and `all()`).

```
def remove_duplicates(x):
    l=0
    for i,item in enumerate(x):
        if any(l==item for l in x)==True:
            print (i,item)
            x=del x[i]
    return(x)
x=[1,2,3,1]
print (remove_duplicates(x))
```

I am getting the following result.

```
0 1
1 3
[2, 1]
```

Instead of [2,3,1].

Comment: using `any()` is not the best option for this task.

Comment: It is generally a bad idea to modify an array as you iterate over it. Work on a copy instead.

Comment: Since `item` is take from `x`, `any(l == item for l in x)` is *always* going to be true.

Comment: @Owen Thank you very much. Forgot that elements would slide down. Found an explination with examples here. https://unspecified.wordpress.com/2009/02/12/thou-shalt-not-modify-a-list-during-iteration/

Comment: @UmeshSaiGurram `if any(l==item for l in x)==True:` is redundant. Just use `if any(l==item for l in x):`

Comment: @junapa Thank you guys.I understood my mistakes. Was trying to learn any all, learnt more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you are trying to learn the use of 'any' and 'all', but it is not a good idea to remove or delete a term while iterating over a list. This is the cause of the unexpected behaviour of your code. 
However, you can use a set to get the existing items in a list/tuple without duplicates. For instance:

```
a = [0,1,3,1,0,3,4,6,4,5]
b = set(a)
print(b)
```

It returns: `set([0,1,3,4,5,6)]`

Please notice that the type of `b` is `'set'`. If you want `b` to be `list` you can use:

```
b = list(set(a))
```

Comment: You might want to clarify that order is not preserved.

Comment: @cricket_007 You are right, it is important to mention the order issue. Thank you for editing my answer, I did not know how to do it.

Comment: Welcome. You can see how to better format question and answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care the order of the sequence, simply do:

```
list(set(x))
```

Comment: His intention is to learn all and any, so this answers helps with nothing at all